# How to write SOAP XML web services in PHP

Tags: php, xml, web-services, soap

I am new in SOAP API web services in PHP, I have to accept XML input and also return in XML. please suggest some code sample. Actually I am working on channel manager for my hotel.

Input XML...

```
<ns3:OTA_HotelResNotifRQ ResStatus="Commit" EchoToken="dsh0a"
xmlns:ns2="http://www.example.com/hotels/channelmgr/"
xmlns:ns3="http://www.example.org/OTA/2003/05/beta">
 <ns3:POS>
 <ns3:Source>
 <ns3:BookingChannel>
 <ns3:CompanyName CompanyShortName="MMYT" Code="MMYT"
CountryCode="IN">Make My Trip</ns3:CompanyName>
 </ns3:BookingChannel>
 </ns3:Source>
 </ns3:POS>
 <ns3:HotelReservations>
 <ns3:HotelReservation ResStatus="Commit" CreateDateTime="2014-05-19">
 <ns3:UniqueID ID="AB123456789012"/>
 <ns3:RoomStays>
 <ns3:RoomStay>
 <ns3:RoomTypes>
 <ns3:RoomType NumberOfUnits="1" RoomTypeCode="Float"/>
 </ns3:RoomTypes>
 <ns3:RatePlans>
 <ns3:RatePlan>
Make My Trip CONFIDENTIAL 7
 <ns3:MealsIncluded MealPlanCodes="CP"/>
 </ns3:RatePlan>
 </ns3:RatePlans>
 <ns3:RoomRates>
 <ns3:RoomRate EffectiveDate="2014-05-20" ExpireDate="2014-05-21"
RatePlanCode="1234567891234"/>
 <ns3:RoomRate EffectiveDate="2014-05-21" ExpireDate="2014-05-22"
RatePlanCode="98765437291739"/>
 </ns3:RoomRates>
 </ns3:RoomStay>
 <ns3:RoomStay>
 <ns3:RoomTypes>
 <ns3:RoomType NumberOfUnits="1" RoomTypeCode="Float"/>
 </ns3:RoomTypes>
 <ns3:RatePlans>
 <ns3:RatePlan>
 <ns3:MealsIncluded MealPlanCodes="CP"/>
 </ns3:RatePlan>
 </ns3:RatePlans>
 <ns3:RoomRates>
 <ns3:RoomRate EffectiveDate="2014-05-20" ExpireDate="2014-05-21"
RatePlanCode="1234567891234"/>

Make My Trip CONFIDENTIAL 8
<ns3:RoomRate EffectiveDate="2014-05-21" ExpireDate="2014-05-22"
RatePlanCode="98765437291739"/>
 </ns3:RoomRates>
 </ns3:RoomStay>
 <ns3:RoomStay>
 <ns3:RoomTypes>
 <ns3:RoomType NumberOfUnits="1" RoomTypeCode="Float"/>
 </ns3:RoomTypes>
 <ns3:RatePlans>
 <ns3:RatePlan>
 <ns3:MealsIncluded MealPlanCodes="CP"/>
 </ns3:RatePlan>
 </ns3:RatePlans>
 <ns3:RoomRates>
 <ns3:RoomRate EffectiveDate="2014-05-20" ExpireDate="2014-05-21"
RatePlanCode="1234567891234"/>
 <ns3:RoomRate EffectiveDate="2014-05-21" ExpireDate="2014-05-22"
RatePlanCode="98765437291739"/>
 </ns3:RoomRates>
 </ns3:RoomStay>
 </ns3:RoomStays>
 <ns3:Services>
 <ns3:Service>
 <ns3:Price>
Make My Trip CONFIDENTIAL 9
 <ns3:AdditionalGuestAmounts AmountBeforeTax="362.00"
CurrencyCode="INR" DecimalPlaces="2"/>
<ns3:Total AmountAfterTax="4249.98" CurrencyCode="INR"
DecimalPlaces="2">
 <ns3:Taxes>
 <ns3:Tax Amount="947.98" CurrencyCode="INR" DecimalPlaces="2">
 <ns3:TaxDescription Name="Hotelier Tax"/>
 </ns3:Tax>
 <ns3:Tax Amount="126.00" CurrencyCode="INR" DecimalPlaces="2">
 <ns3:TaxDescription Name="TDS"/>
 </ns3:Tax>
 </ns3:Taxes>
 </ns3:Total>
 </ns3:Price>
 <ns3:ServiceDetails>
 <ns3:GuestCounts>
 <ns3:GuestCount AgeQualifyingCode="10" Count="6"/>
 <ns3:GuestCount AgeQualifyingCode="8" Count="2"/>
 </ns3:GuestCounts>
 </ns3:ServiceDetails>
 </ns3:Service>
 </ns3:Services>
 <ns3:ResGuests>
 <ns3:ResGuest PrimaryIndicator="true">
Make My Trip CONFIDENTIAL 10
 <ns3:Profiles>
 <ns3:ProfileInfo>
 <ns3:Profile>
 <ns3:Customer>
 <ns3:PersonName>
 <ns3:GivenName>Test</ns3:GivenName>
 </ns3:PersonName>
 </ns3:Customer>
 </ns3:Profile>
 </ns3:ProfileInfo>
 </ns3:Profiles>
 </ns3:ResGuest>
 </ns3:ResGuests>
 <ns3:ResGlobalInfo>
 <ns3:TimeSpan Start="2014-05-20" End="2014-05-22"/>
 <ns3:CancelPenalties>
 <ns3:CancelPenalty>
 <ns3:PenaltyDescription>
 <ns3:Text># More than 2 days before check-in date: FREE CANCELLATION; 2
days before check-in date: 1 night cost will be charged as
cancellation fee; In case of no show: no refund; An additional
MakeMyTrip service charge of INR 250 will apply
</ns3:Text>
 </ns3:PenaltyDescription>
Make My Trip CONFIDENTIAL 11
 </ns3:CancelPenalty>
 </ns3:CancelPenalties>
 <ns3:HotelReservationIDs>
 <ns3:HotelReservationID ResID_Type="14" ResID_Value="AB123456789012"
ResID_Date="2014-05-19"/>
 </ns3:HotelReservationIDs>
 <ns3:BasicPropertyInfo HotelCode="987654321987654321" HotelName="The
test test"/>
 </ns3:ResGlobalInfo>
 </ns3:HotelReservation>
 </ns3:HotelReservations>
 </ns3:OTA_HotelResNotifRQ>
```

Output XML...

```
<OTA_HotelResNotifRS
xmlns="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05/beta" Version="1.0"
TimeStamp="2012-04-27T10:56:34" EchoToken="UUicg">
<Success />
 <HotelReservations>
 <HotelReservation>
 <UniqueID Type="14" ID="AB123456789" />
 <ResGlobalInfo>
 <HotelReservationIDs>
 <HotelReservationID ResID_Type="14"
ResID_Value=" YourConfirmationNo " />
 </HotelReservationIDs>
 </ResGlobalInfo>
 </HotelReservation>
 </HotelReservations>
</OTA_HotelResNotifRS>
```

Comment: It this a new application and you can go for any technologies you want, or it has been already started and it is based on some framework? If so, on which one?

Comment: Dear Michal, its a SOAP(Simple Object Access Protocol), I want ti write in PHP. Have you any idea in PHP? have you written any web service using SOAP?

Comment: PHP comes with built-in SOAP support in form of SoapClient and SoapServer, here you can find it: http://php.net/manual/en/book.soap.php . Some frameworks have wrappers for it, so if you are using one, then you should check if that's the case for yours. But if you have fresh application, then you don't need to worry about that.